# Check for existence of classes on click (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to check to see if a particular element, when clicked, has a specified class. I know that you can bind a click handler which passes `e.target` to the handler. My thinking was to get `e.target.classList.indexOf(this.myClass) > -1` to see if it has the class, but I get the following error.

> e.target.classList.indexOf is not a function

I assume this is because `classList` is an *array-like* object, and not an actual array. Is there a simpler way to get a list of classes from a clicked element in React without performing all of the "slice call" magic?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myClass = 'my-class';
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        // check if e.target class has this.myClass
        if (/* logic */) {
            // perform action
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} className={this.myClass + ' other-class'}>
            <div>My Component</div>
        </div>
    }

}
```

**How can I get an array of classes from the "target" element of a click in React's event system?**

Comment: In react  you can base your logic on the state (that you probably use to assign the class names), instead of the class names themselves.

Comment: If I'm assigning a click handler to an outer element, and want it to fire *only* when the outer element is clicked (not the inner elements), how would I do this check without checking class names?

Comment: I’d prefer comparing the event target with the outer div, to avoid messing with the class name. `if (e.target === ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)) …`

Comment: @jokka - that was my thought exactly. The only caveat is that it doesn't work with stateless components. However, this is not the case here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Element.classList` provides a `contains()` function which should solve your issue:

```
e.target.classList.contains(this.myClass)
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

---

Also note that `this` may not be what you think it is in your event handler, unless you bind the function context explicitly, e.g. using `bind()`.

Comment: Yep, forgot about adding the `onClick` altogether, thanks for the tip with `contains()`!

Comment: In some cases `e.target` would be mistaken by other component, unless you deal with the bubble nightmare yourself. Just went trhu it right now. I suggest using `e.currentTarget` instead if yout want to get the exact same tag you attached the event to.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) method.,

> `contains( String )` Checks if specified class value exists in class
>   attribute of the element.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myClass = 'my-class';
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.classList.contains(this.myClass))
  }

  render() {
    return <div 
      className={this.myClass + ' other-class'} 
      onClick={this.handleClick}
    >
      <div>My Component</div>
    </div>
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```